# Dolphin key bindings to switch between tabs?

Tags: kde, dolphin

If you use a web browser and press Alt+1, Alt+2, Alt+3, ..., you can switch to tab 1, tab 2, tab 3, etc.

This kind of behavior is very convenient and I'd like behave not only Firefox and tons of other applications this way but Dolphin as well. How can I configure Dolphin to have this kind of behavior? (The default behavior to automatically select characters in the title as "hotkeys" is completely useless.)

Note: This is not about cycling through tabs. I don't want to cycle through tabs. There is no reason for such a thing as typically in Dolphin you will open only a few directories. What I'd like to do is to address each of these tabs directly by a keyboard shortcut such as "Alt+1", "Alt+2", etc.

Comment: Default Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Dolphin version 17.12.3. How does that help?

Comment: Should be a default feature, probably existing for decades. At least that's what I'd expect. It took me quite some time to figure out how to configure that for the KDE terminal window, I'm assuming it is somehow a similar situation for Dolphin?

Comment: Sound's like a typical Linux thing: A lot of fantastic fancy stuff is implemented (for decades), but if you want to have some very fundamental basics as well, you need to look for "guidance" ... Or build it yourself from scratch (starting another OS project). Having the year 2019 this is somehow quite disappointing.